# Reorganizing .net code by compiling to ast and then decompiling

Tags: .net, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, decompiling

Is there a way to compile asp.net code to its AST and then de-compiling it back into VB with all the symbols and comments in place like local variables, comments etc., but with the structure of the file re-ordered to follow a common structure like:

Variables ordered alphabetically:

1. Public Class variables
2. Public Shared Class variables
3. Private Class variables
4. Private Shared Class variables

Methods / functions alphabetically:

1. Public class methods
2. Public Static Class methods
3. Private class methods
4. Private Static Class methods

etc...

Its important that the files must still be able to compile.

The usecase is a set of projects that have a bunch of common code but this code has forked to such a point that many of these "common" libraries have changed over time. At this point,it is very cumbersome to share code improvements from one project with the other projects. The end goal I would like to see all the common code for these projects put to the top of the files and the unique code moved to the bottom of the files. This would allow for easier maintenance of these libraries.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/ "do not plan to evolve", so you should pay attention to your VB.NET investment. There are tons of code converters you might build upon, like https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter but Microsoft does not yet have its own.

Comment: Thanks Lex. Guess its time to buy VisualSt^&!@o er... Studio. Been avoiding this day for a good chunk of my live. Nothing beats a good programmers editor, logging and %tail -f IMHO =)